# Most maintainable way to search in various columns

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, linq

A table has a column for Categories which hold integers representing Property, Cars, Others.

There are different columns of interest for each category shown below such that keywords searching for property will focus on columns for PropertyType, State, County, and NoOfBaths; while keyword searching for cars will focus on make, model, year and so on.

All entries have data in all columns but the data might sometimes have a slightly different meaning for different categories. For instance, PropertyType columns holds CarType data for cars and ItemType data for others, but the columns is only of interest when searching property.

**Property**
PropertyType,
Location State,
Location County,
No of Baths

**Cars**
Make,
Model,
Year,
Location State

**Others**
Itemname,
Make,
Colour,
Location State

The columns of interest were limited to four for performance reasons. A single search text box is used in the UI just like google. The algorithm used to pre identify the user’s search category before the query is fired posts an acceptable 98% accuracy rate. The algorithm also makes a good guess of what could be colour, state, county etc.
The site started as a small ads site developed using c#, entity framework, SQL server.

Since it was conceived as a small project, I thought I could pull it off with linq to entities. Using if statements to eliminate null fields, they were a finite number of queries (2 to the power 4) for each category.

Eg. 1

and some listings for the queryHelper

where the null value is checked before the where clause is composed.

By the time I was done, I was not sure if a small project like that deserved this kind of logic even though it seemed more flexible and maintainable.  The columns of interest could be changed without affecting the code.

The question is if there is an easier way to achieve this?

Secondly, why isn’t there an ‘Ignorable()’ function in linq such that a given portion of the where clause can be ignored if the value being compared is null or empty?

Eg. 1 modifed

```
var results = context.Items.Where(m=>m.make.Ignorable() == make && 
m.model.Ignorable() == model && m.year.Ignorable() ==year && 
m.state.Ignorable() == state);
```

…

Or a symbol, say ‘¬’, which achieves the same like so
Eg. 1 modifed

```
var results = context.Items.Where(m=>m.make ¬== make && m.model ¬== model 
&& m.year ¬==year && m.state ¬== state);
```

…

Answer (score 0):

I think much easier and maintainable way for doing this is an `overrided Equals()` method in the particular class. So that any changes in the properties need not to alter the Linq queries. Let me explain this with the help of an example class, let it be the class `Cars` consider the definition of class will be like this:

```
public class Cars
{    
     // Properties      
     public string Make { get; set; }
     public string Model { get; set; }
     public int Year { get; set; }
     public string Location_State { get; set; }

     // overrided  Equals method definition
     public override bool Equals(object obj)
     {
         return this.Equals(obj as Cars);
     }
     public bool Equals(Cars other)
     {
         if (other == null)
             return false;
         return (this.Make == other.Make) &&
                (this.Model == other.Model) &&
                (this.Year == other.Year) &&
                (this.Location_State == other.Location_State);
     }
}
```

Now let `objCars` be the object you wanted to compare with the cars in the `context.Items` then you can format your LINQ query like this:

```
context.Items.Where(m=> m.Equals(objCars));
```

**Note :** You can give the `N` number of conditions in the `Equals` method so that you can avoid checking is null or empty or what ever else each time before executing the LINQ or even withing the LINQ. Easily made property changes to the class, you need to alter the condition in the overrieded method only

Comment: Cars objCars = new Cars() {  model = "favmodel", year = "2017", locationState = "mystate" }; In this case, objCars.make will be null by default and return (this.Make == other.Make) &&...will return cars where make == NULL instead of omitting the make test as in  
                return (this.Model == other.Model) &&
                (this.Year == other.Year) &&
                (this.Location_State == other.Location_State);

Comment: As I already said, you can modify the conditions to get the comparison more effective

Comment: You can't overload equals when using a Linq2Entities system like EntityFramework

Answer (score 0):

```
 var q = context.Items;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(make))
        {
            q = q.Where(m => m.make == make);
        }
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(model))
        {
            q = q.Where(m => m.model == model);
        }
        //. . .

        var results = q.ToList();
```

The query could be manipulated in multiple lines before being executed. See [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/3a1185ae-c798-4326-b10c-6518b189a1f5/most-maintainable-way-to-perform-linq-search-in-various-columns?forum=csharpgeneral#3a1185ae-c798-4326-b10c-6518b189a1f5)